# Unable to call export methods using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to call export method after importing using Node.js but its not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

> settings.js::

```
const axios = require('axios');
let protocol = '';
let opticalIp = '';

let env = {
    API_URL: '',
    configHeaders: ''
};


axios.get(`https://IP:9201/api/v1.0/settings/custom-form/Optical`).then(function(response) {
    //console.log('succ', response);
    if(response.data && response.data.data) {
        protocol = response.data.data['scheme'];
        opticalIp = response.data.data['optical_ip'];
        env.API_URL = `${protocol}://${opticalIp}/`;
        console.log('dataenv', env);
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error', error);
});

module.exports = {
    fetchOptical: () => {
        console.log('fetch optical');
        axios.get(`https://IP:9201/api/v1.0/settings/custom-form/Optical`).then(function(response) {
            //console.log('succ', response);
            if(response.data && response.data.data) {
                protocol = response.data.data['scheme'];
                opticalIp = response.data.data['optical_ip'];
                env.API_URL = `${protocol}://${opticalIp}/`;
                console.log('fetch', env);
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    }
}


module.exports = env;
```

The above file I am exporting to other file which is given below.

```
const config = require('../../config/settings');
getDiscoveryRoutes = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.includes("Bearer ")) {
            responseObj = {
                status: 'Error',
                msg: 'Please add token to headers',
                body: {}
            };
            res.send(responseObj);
        } else {
            config.fetchOptical;
            let token = req.headers.authorization;
            let configHeaders = {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            }
            console.log('discovery', config.API_URL);
            axios.get(`${config.API_URL}endpoints/optical/routes/discovered`, configHeaders).then(function(response) {
                responseObj = {
                    status: 'success',
                    msg: 'Record fetched successfully',
                    body: response.data
                };
                res.send(responseObj);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                responseObj = {
                    status: 'Error',
                    msg: 'Error occured.',
                    body: error.response.data['service-response']['payload']['message'] || 'Operation not found'
                };
                res.status(error.response.status).send(responseObj);
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error::', error);
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to call `config.fetchOptical` to set `env` variable again with latest value but in my case that `fetchOptical` method is not called at all. I need to set the `env` variable again by calling `fetchOptical` method. Please help me to get the right solution.

Comment: `config.fetchOptical;` This is not how you call a function.

Comment: @tkausl; whats the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwriting `module.exports` twice. `module.exports` is just a field of `module` object. So firstly you are doing

```
module.exports = {
    fetchOptical: () => {
        console.log('fetch optical');
        axios.get(`https://IP:9201/api/v1.0/settings/custom-form/Optical`).then(function(response) {
            //console.log('succ', response);
            if(response.data && response.data.data) {
                protocol = response.data.data['scheme'];
                opticalIp = response.data.data['optical_ip'];
                env.API_URL = `${protocol}://${opticalIp}/`;
                console.log('fetch', env);
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    }
}
```

And that is okay and should work. But then very next line

```
module.exports = env;
```

You overwrote the previous object. And now `module.exports` holds `env`. To fix that you can either remove this line of code or do the following to export both `fetchOptical` and `env` at the same time.

```
module.exports = {
    fetchOptical: () => {
        console.log('fetch optical');
        axios.get(`https://IP:9201/api/v1.0/settings/custom-form/Optical`).then(function(response) {
            //console.log('succ', response);
            if(response.data && response.data.data) {
                protocol = response.data.data['scheme'];
                opticalIp = response.data.data['optical_ip'];
                env.API_URL = `${protocol}://${opticalIp}/`;
                console.log('fetch', env);
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    },
    env,
}
```

Comment: Instead of `module.exports`, you can use `exports`. So it will be like `exports.funcName` and `exports.env` in the same file.